Pydentic BaseModel for langchain openai structured tools
I have a function that I'm going to use as tool :
def run(run_config:dict={}):
pass

run_config is the single parameter that has more parameters inside as a key value pair. I'm not sure whether to use a nested model like this:
class ToolInput(BaseModel):
run_config : ConfigParams

class ConfigParams(BaseModels):
....some params that can be inside run_config

or just simply using a model that indicates parameters that comes inside of run_config works like this:
class ToolInput(BaseModel):
....some params that can be inside run_config

I have tried nested one and it doesn't seems to be working and agent stuck infinitely on run.
